# Como configurar o arquivo webpack no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

Estou seguindo vários tutoriais como podem ver abaixo;

**Aos 9 minutos e 45 segundos de vídeo.**

[Utilização do Vue.js em uma aplicação Laravel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGSJjDahlrQ&t=336s)

**Aos 8 minutos e 12 segundos do vídeo.**

[1 - CRUD en LARAVEL & VUEjs - Webpack, Laravel Mix, NPM, Axios | Rimorsoft Online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EKLN_1mNW8&list=PLhCiuvlix-rSduJ-vKGpPj5xxcmeLabXc)

**Aos 4 minutos 36 segundos de vídeo**

[CRUD with Vue JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qA5PlSh1Qq8&t=1797s)

Eu sei que tem como configurar direto na pagina os arquivos de vuejs e bootstrap, mas eu gostaria de configurar no arquivo **webpack.mix.js** o css e o Javascript, pois configurando no **webpack.mix.js** vai ficar configurado para o projeto todo;

Eu tentei dessa forma, mas não deu certo, eu tentei pelos tutoriais de vídeo, mas também não tive sucesso, aceito sugestões;

```
mix.js(
  'resources/assets/js/app.js',
  ''
   'public/js')
   .sass(
     'resources/assets/sass/app.scss',
     '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
      'public/css');
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria você não usar Vue integrado dessa forma com o Laravel, eu sugiro que leia este [artigo](https://blog.codecasts.com.br/laravel-vue-js-whatever-1f3d0d688d06) que explica muito bem o porquê.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim

Dentro do arquivo `ressources/sass/app.scss` você importa o bootstrap:

```
// Bootstrap
@import 'node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Em `webpack.mix.js` você escreve assim:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Ai no final de  tudo vc vai lá no `console` e roda o comando:

```
npm run dev
```

Pronto, ambos estão no `public` do Laravel, pronto para vc utilizar nos projetos...

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```